# Resizable sticky footer overlaps content - fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In my layout I have created the following jsfiddle-hosted resizable sticky footer. However, on the resize it overlaps the content. Is there anyway to make it responsive on all browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/9aLc0mg2/

```
$(function () {

    $('.footer').resizable({
     handles: 'n, s'
    }).bind('resize', function(){
      $(this).css("top", "auto");
    });

});


<div class="footer">
   <p> footer content here </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able after digging more in research to solve it by adding the following function

```
var bumpIt = function() {
      $('body').css('margin-bottom', $('.footer').height());
    },
    didResize = false;

bumpIt();

$(window).resize(function() {
  didResize = true;
});
setInterval(function() {
  if(didResize) {
    didResize = false;
    bumpIt();
  }
}, 250);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v71tsx97/

Also could be done this way: http://jsfiddle.net/mnuxohoj/

But still any other methods with better performance are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be resizable back down ? Triedd the disable method but it does not work for some reason. Got it to stop at the content above it though. Is this any good ? 
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9aLc0mg2/2/)

```
$(function () {
 var topheight = $('#top').height();
 var topoffset = $("#top").offset();     
 var topbottom = topoffset.top + topheight;

$('.footer').resizable({
 handles: 'n, s'
}).bind('resize', function(){
   $(this).css("top","auto");


      var footeroffset = $(this).offset();
      var footerheight = $(this).height();
      var footerBottom= footeroffset.top + footerheight;

     $("#res").html(topbottom+"  "+footeroffset.top);
    if(topbottom + 50 >= footeroffset.top){
        $('#res').html("should disable");        
        $('.footer').resizable("destroy");
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Not sure as I didn't face this issue. I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v71tsx97/ so you can recheck. Thank you anyway your solution also works.

Comment: What about changing the adding a function when the window is resized ? something like ` $( window ).resize(function() {
        $( ".footer" ).css("position","relative !important");
});` You could also change z index so it doesn't overlap